# how can i make url shortener api in express.js?

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I'm doing a link shortener. The link shortener works very well but now I'm trying to do API for it. The problem is that if I pass the URL argument in the get URL it's not working. I tried a lot of things but it's not working. When I do like http://localhost:3500/api/create/google.com it works but when I do http://localhost:3500/api/create/https://google.com it's not working because of the https://. These are the last 3 inputs via my API that failed: http://https:google.com, google.com, http://
I'm using express and mongoose. Here's my code:

```
app.get('/api/create/:shortUrl(*)', async (req, res, next) => {
if (req.params.shortUrl.includes("https://") || req.params.shortUrl.includes("http://") || req.params.shortUrl.includes("/")) {
    req.params.shortUrl = req.params.shortUrl.replace("https://", "").replace("http://", "").replace("/", "")
}
if (req.params.shortUrl == "") {
    res.send("invalid URL")
}
    await shorturl.create({full: `http://${req.params.shortUrl}`})
    const shortUrls = await shorturl.find().sort({_id: -1}).limit(-1)
    const latest = shortUrls[0]
    res.send("https://p33t.link/" + latest.short)
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to properly encode portions of the URL that contain restricted characters such as `:` and `//` that aren't part of the actual protocol to make it a legal URL.  So, the idea is that you encode the "parameter" before appending it to the URL.  Presumably, you would use [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), depending upon exactly where you're placing it in the URL.

After parsing the core part of the URL, a web server will decode the remaining components of the URL and give you back the original characters.  I would suggest that your particular use would probably work better as a query parameter rather than a part of the path which would give you this when properly encoded:

```
http://localhost:3500/api/create?u=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com
```

And, you could then use:

```
app.get('/api/create', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.query.u);
    ...
});
```